# Add Google Chart to HUGO markdown (.md) file

Tags: hugo

I have started to create a Hugo website using the following theme: https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/academic/. I would like to add a Google Chart.

**Question:** How can I add a google chart as the [header] to a page created by the following .md file?

```
+++
title = "Back to the Future"
date = "2010-09-01"

authors = ["Smith S."]
publication_types = ["2"]

# Publication name and optional abbreviated version.
publication = "*Nature*, vol. 28, no. 3, pp. 1-12"
publication_short = "*Nature*"

# Abstract and optional shortened version.
abstract = "..."

# Featured image thumbnail (optional)
image_preview = ""

math = true
highlight = true

[header]
image = ""
caption = ""
+++
```

**The Google chart that I would like add:**

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['date','z','test'],
    ['Q1-2001',1.69,1.66847553787712],
    ['Q2-2001',1.69,1.61360500808427],
    ['Q3-2001',1.42,1.49374423981914],
    ['Q4-2001',1.4,1.35653146853147],
          ]);

        var options = {
           title: 't',
           curveType: 'none',
           width: 1500,
           height: 800,
           vAxis: {title: 'y'},
           hAxis: {title: 'x'},
           seriesType: 'scatter',
           series: {
            1: {
              type: 'line'
            }
        }
    };

         var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the html to your markdown file where you want it, i.e.:

```
+++
# frontmatter
+++

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['date','z','test'],
  ['Q1-2001',1.69,1.66847553787712],
  ['Q2-2001',1.69,1.61360500808427],
  ['Q3-2001',1.42,1.49374423981914],
  ['Q4-2001',1.4,1.35653146853147],
]);
var options = {
   title: 't',
   curveType: 'none',
   width: 1500,
   height: 800,
   vAxis: {title: 'y'},
   hAxis: {title: 'x'},
   seriesType: 'scatter',
   series: {
    1: {
      type: 'line'
    }
}
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>

your markdown content
```

To add it as header instead, in your layout you would have to add a partial file under the `layouts/partials/` folder, and specify in your post frontmatter that you want to use the partial, then include it in your layout, something like:

```
{{ if .Params.google_charts }}
  {{ partial "header.html" . }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: I am trying to add the Google chart as the header to the page. It would be also great to understand how to simply add a google chart anywhere on the page. I have already tried what you suggest, does this work for you?

Comment: sorry, I removed newlines from the script file and it should work now, I have tested it. I also edited my answer to show how to add it in the header.